# how to retrieve data from JSON Array?

Tags: javascript, json

here is my json data

```
{
"list":[{"rank":"1","fb_id":"12345","score":"3000"},
        {"rank":"2","fb_id":"12345","score":"2000"},      
        {"rank":"3","fb_id":"123456","score":"1000"},
        {"rank":"5","fb_id":"123456","score":"2500"}],
       "roundscores":[{"score1":"1000","pos1":"3","score2":"2500","pos2":"5"}]
}
```

from this data i need to get `score1` using java script

my JS

```
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "ajaxClassifica2.jsp",
data: "selectedLevel="+selectedLevel+"&fb_id="+123456,
success: function(data) {
        alert(data);
        var jsonlist = data.list;
        var jsonround = data.roundscores;
        alert(jsonlist); 
        alert(jsonround);
        var strBuild = "";
        $.each(jsonobj, function(index, names) 
        {
                strBuild ="<ul class=\"livelli\">"
                            +" <div class=\"social\"> "
                            +"  <a href=\"#\"><img src=\"images/ico_fb.png\"></a>"
                            +"  <a href=\"#\"><img src=\"images/ico_tw.png\"></a>"
                            +" </div>"
                            +" <li><strong>Round 1:</strong> " + names.roundscores.score1 + "</li>"
                            +" <li><strong>Posizione:</strong> " + names.roundscores.pos1 + " </li>"
                            +" </ul>"
                            +" <ul class=\"livelli\">"
                            +" <div class=\"social\"> "
                            +"  <a href=\"#\"><img src=\"images/ico_fb.png\"></a>"
                            +"      <a href=\"#\"><img src=\"images/ico_tw.png\"></a>"
                            +" </div>"
                            +" <li><strong>Round 2:</strong> " + names.roundscores.score2 + "</li>"
                            +" <li><strong>Posizione:</strong> " + names.roundscores.pos2 + "</li>"
                            +" </ul>";

        });
              }
    });
```

Comment: Did you try anything yourself?

Comment: You should post your code and let everyone see what you have done.

Comment: yes i tried
alert(data);
var jsonlist = data.list;
var jsonround = data.roundscores;

while alerting data i could see my json data
the rest comes undefined

Comment: You need to _parse_ the data before you can use it.

Comment: `roundscores` is an array. That's why you need `[0]` to access the first index/object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`JSON.parse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) then access it using normal JavaScript nomenclature:

```
var obj = JSON.parse('{"list":[...]}');
obj.roundscores[0].score1 // 1000
```

Also, if you're working with older browsers that don't have the `JSON.parse` API, you can use a polyfill such as [`JSON3`](http://bestiejs.github.io/json3/)

Comment: can you please help me to print the list array in a html.
<ul class="lista tit">
                 <li>pos</li>
                 <li>nome</li>
                 <li>punti</li>
 </ul>

Answer (score 2):

```
var json = '{ "list":[{"rank":"1","fb_id":"12345","score":"3000"},{"rank":"2","fb_id":"12345","score":"2000"},{"rank":"3","fb_id":"123456","score":"1000"},{"rank":"5","fb_id":"123456","score":"2500"}], "roundscores":[{"score1":"1000","pos1":"3","score2":"2500","pos2":"5"}] }';
var obj = JSON.parse(json);
var score1 = obj.roundscores[0].score1);
```

Comment: can you please help me to print the list array in a html. <ul class="lista tit"> <li>pos</li> <li>nome</li> <li>punti</li> </ul>

Answer (score 0):

Lest suppose your JSON data is in variable "rawData".

```
var jData = JSON.parse(rawData);
alert(jData.roundscores[0].score1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Review this example might be helpful for you

```
         var jsonText = '{"name":"Frodo","address":"Hobbiton, The Shire"}';
         var person = JSON.parse(jsonText);

         alert(person.name);
```